# Split regex strings into new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a redirect file in a pandas dataframe with a number of regex "or" expressions.

| regex_no | regex |
| --- | --- |
| Regex4 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/(brand-|)jon-richard/ |
| Regex5 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/(bracelets|necklaces|)/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ |
| Regex245 | /shop/(fashion/dresses/occasion-dresses|)/bridesmaid/ |

I'm looking to build a testUrl column which builds both versions of the regex in a test url to run automated tests. It would look like this.

| regex_no | regex | testUrl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Regex4 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/(brand-|)jon-richard/ | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/brand-jon-richard/ |
| Regex4 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/(brand-|)jon-richard/ | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/jon-richard/ |
| Regex5 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/(bracelets|necklaces|)/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ | /shop/accessories/jewellery/bracelets/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ |
| Regex5 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/(bracelets|necklaces|)/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ | /shop/accessories/jewellery/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ |
| Regex5 | /shop/accessories/jewellery/(bracelets|necklaces|)/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ | /shop/accessories/jewellery/necklaces/brand-simply-silver-by-jon-richard/ |
| Regex245 | /shop/(fashion/dresses/occasion-dresses/|)bridesmaid/ | /shop/fashion/dresses/occasion-dresses/bridesmaid/ |
| Regex245 | /shop/(fashion/dresses/occasion-dresses/|)bridesmaid/ | /shop/bridesmaid/ |

Unfortunately, I've no code to show how I would approach this, as it's slightly out of my knowledge capability. Thanks

Comment: If you have no code, how are you using pandas and seeing the dataframe?

Comment: Point taken, I've amended the question. 
I have the code for the dataframe and other manipulations I've carried out, but wouldn't have been relevant to show for this question.

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the rows of the dataframe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370553/5229301), then use [exrex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370553/5229301) to grab each possible result of your regex expressions.
You would need to construct a new dataframe, adding a new row for every possible result that exrex generates.
Might look something like (completely untested):

```
import pandas as pd
import exrex

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = ['regex_no','regex','testUrl'])
for i in range(0, len(originalDataFrame)):
    for url in exrex.generate(originalDataFrame.iloc(i)['regex']):
        df2.append(originalDataFrame.iloc(i).concat(url))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try